# Adding Widgets to Draft Pages

Tags: widgets

I'm trying to work out how to add widgets (ie images, text and tweeter feeds) to the left hand side panel of new pages that are in draft format.

I've got 18 new pages with each representing a sports team. I'm somewhat aware of how to add all the widgets post publishing the pages but I'd rather set it all up before hand to ensure no issues before I go live.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Note this is on self hosted wordpress.org.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you preview a page while it still is in draft, you can see the full effect of the page, including the widgets

Comment: I completely understand this. However, I want to add specific widgets to these specific pages. How do I do that? Currently I use a plugin called Display Widgets that allows me to assign widgets to specific pages but it doesn't give the option to assign them to a draft page. I don't want the same widgets that I have on my home page.

Answer (score 0):

As you note in your comment there are plugins that allow you to insert different widgets on different types of pages. If the plugin doesn't include the possibility you need, you'll have to build it yourself.

First, you'll have to familiarize yourself with [how to add widget areas (sidebars)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Sidebars) to your (child) theme. It isn't that difficult. You will learn that after some work you'll get an extra sidebar to fill with widgets in the admin area and that you can insert that sidebar in your theme with code like this:

```
if (is_active_sidebar('my_sidebar'))  // test if there are widgets in the sidebar
  dynamic_sidebar ('my_sidebar'); // display the sidebar
```

Now, you want to show a different sidebar for draft and published posts. You can easily do this by testing for the post status using [`get_post_status`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status) and display a different sidebar depending on the result, like this:

```
$status = get_post_status();
if ($status == 'draft') {
  if (is_active_sidebar('my_draft_sidebar')) dynamic_sidebar ('my_draft_sidebar');
  }
else {
  if (is_active_sidebar('my_sidebar')) dynamic_sidebar ('my_sidebar');
  }
```

Beware that if you have stuff like a 'recent post widget' your draft will likely not be shown, because the widget only checks for published posts.